# Is there a python equivalent to Matlab's highpass function?

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, highpass-filter

I am replicating an old code I had written in matlab which involves filtering signals using Matlab's highpass function (https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/highpass.html). Can anyone refer me to a python-equivalent to this function if one exists? If not, are there any references online so that I can maybe code this function myself? Anything helps :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same, but for simple highpass filtering is enough: (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html).

Care if using filter order `N > 10`, it had some issues.